# Is this set-builder notation: $\{(x,y): x\in\mathbb{R}\land y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ an extensional definition of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I entered university in France two weeks ago. In one of our math course entitled "Reasoning and sets", we were introduced basic notion about sets and how they are defined.

We saw that sets can be defined by extension or by intension and our teacher gave us some examples of extensional and intensional definitions.

Because I already knew what were set-builder notation (a notation that even if it's used in France don't have any explicit name in French...), extensional and intensional definition, I was surprised to see that our teacher considered that P = $\{(x,y): x\in\mathbb{R}\land y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and D = $\{(1-t,2+t): t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ were extensive definitions. I thought the two were intensive definitions.

Considering that the definition of an extensive set definition is that we list all elements in the set, how can theses definition be extensive ? We are not listing all elements of the set but giving conditions for that an object be part of this set.

So are theses two set definition extensive definitions ? Also, I think that all set definitions made with set-builder notation are intensive. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I think that the distinction is not so clear-cut... See [Intensional definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensional_and_intensional_definitions#Intensional_definition) : "It is impossible to give an extensional definition for a term with an *infinite* set of referents, but an intensional one can often be stated concisely – there are infinitely many *even* numbers, impossible to list, but the term "even numbers" can be defined easily by saying that even numbers are integer multiples of two." 1/2

Comment: Thus, according to this elucidation, you are right: there are infinitely many *real* numbers and we cannot "list" them all. But a definition like: $E = \{ x \mid x \text { is even } \}$ can be considered an "extensive definition" or it is only a trick ? 2/2

Comment: You need know if you're seeing a Axiomatic Set Theory, because the axiom of extension is a rigorous definition of construction of classes